# Error in query using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to join tables but always get the error

> The multi-part identifier could not be bound

I have 3 tables `Drivers`, `Request` and `Journey`. I have `driver_id` foreign key in `Journey`. How can I join these tables to get details of all three tables??

```
Select driver.driver_name 
from Drivers,
     Journey 
where driver.id = journey.id 
  and driver.id=1;
```

Comment: You will need to show the query - Ensure that columns that appear in both joined tables are disambiguated with their owning table prefix or alias; `select table1.column ...`

Comment: Your table is name `drivers` yet you reference an alias named `driver` (note the missing `s`)

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when an alias is used when referencing a column in a SELECT statement and the alias used is not defined anywhere in the FROM clause of the SELECT statement.
For more details visit [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-4104.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You only seem to be joining two of your three tables - correct?

The proper, ANSI SQL-92 standard-compliant way to do this would be:

```
SELECT 
    driver.driver_name 
FROM
    Drivers
INNER JOIN
    Journey ON driver.id = journey.id 
WHERE
    driver.id = 1;
```

This is using the **ANSI standard** (in place since **1992** - more than 20 years now!) `JOIN` syntax of `INNER JOIN` (there's also `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, `FULL JOIN` and a few more) instead of just comma-separating a list of tables in the `FROM` clause.

See Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) on that topic, too.

Answer (score -1):

driver+s

```
Select Drivers.driver_name 
from Drivers,
     Journey 
where Drivers.id = journey.id 
  and Drivers.id=1;
```